# Copy single template to multiple file names

Tags: php

I'm having a little trouble with a multi file creation. I've taken the code
from my another project that actually creates pages one at a time in order.

Trying to get it to create multiple pages of a given template.php file.

I'm not getting any errors in the logs and nothing in destination.
With not understanding loops well enough it's getting lost.

Thanks in advance

```
<?php

// copy template.php -> page1.php, page2.php, page3.php etc...

$area = $_POST["area"];
// Get number of needed pages
$numberofpages = $_POST["pagenumber"];
// Location of template.php
$templatelocation = "/var/work.files/template.php";
// Send copied files to the requested location.
$filedestination = "/var/work.files/$area";

for ($i = 1; $i < $numberofpages; ++$i) {
    // Check if file name is already there. If there is continue to next in order
    if (!file_exists($filedestination . '/page'. $i . '.php')) {
        // get filename and copy template to it ...
        $filename = "page$i.php";
        copy('$templatelocation', '$filedestination/$filename');
       //continue until number of requested pages created
    }
}

?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You used quotes incorrectly in your code.
Variables are not interpolated inside single quotes.

Change

```
copy('$templatelocation', '$filedestination/$filename');
```

to

```
copy($templatelocation, "$filedestination/$filename");
```

Comment: Note that the quotes are not "incorrect", just that he is using them incorrectly. If you are going to use single quotes (`'`), then you have to concatenate the string. Double-quotes (`"`) are parsed for values, so concatenation isn't required. `copy($templatelocation, $filedestination.'/'.$filename);` would work just as well.

Comment: This helped. Now I'm getting some other errors of things wrong. It shows the number of pages requested, and file names but it's one short on the names requested, and nothing is created. Getting a failed to open stream file error. Now to work on the rest. Thanks. I'll post that need on another.

Comment: I found the rest of it. Thanks so much.

Answer (score 1):

Your code is incorrect just remove the quotes `''` and insert another type of quotes `""`.

```
  copy($templatelocation, $filedestination."/".$filename);
```

OR

```
 copy($templatelocation, "$filedestination/$filename");
```

instead of

```
copy('$templatelocation', '$filedestination/$filename');
```

Hope this helps you

Comment: Your first example is not valid code -- the forward slash must be quoted as a string.

Comment: @Chris Thanks for telling the error. Now i have corrected it

Comment: I gave a plus one, the other guy beat you by 2 minutes. But thank you for help.